# Double deadbolt with screw cap

Tags: security, deadbolt

I purchased a Schlage double deadbolt B62N V 619. For my gate. It comes with a special B62 screw and a cap to hide it. How can I secure the cap so it doesn't fall off? I'm tempted to use glue...

[image: deadbolt B62 screw and cap]

Comment: The cap is designed to be held in with compression. If you need to access the special screw, then glue would be a severe hindrance. Gluing it in will not deter determined forcing of the lock but only cause *you* a problem.

Comment: I push it in but falls off. When the gate is closed the screw side is very close to a sliding door which makes putting a screw driver very difficult and would need to either open the gate or sliding door first. Even if you could remove the screw it would hit against the sliding door.

Comment: I'd try something like wood glue (pva), so it would be somewhat stuck but not impossible to remove in the future. (Tip: put a strip of masking tape over it while it sets for a couple of days.)

Comment: I don't get the concern about interference of the screw with a sliding door. If you want to remove the screw (to remove the lock) you could open the sliding door or the gate, couldn't you? And how often do need to access the screw? Use enough wood glue to hold in the plug like @Aloysius Defenestrate suggests.

Comment: @JimStewart I meant that you would need to open the sliding door first to be able to get to the screws out and open the gate. Hence the "security". Unless it starts failing due to sun and rain, I won't be removing. Hopefully it lasts a long time.

Comment: Had a problem when tightening the screws. When I tested the key it was very hard and if I fully extended the deadbolt and removed the key, I could close it with my finger since it retracted a bit when turning they key back to remove. I'm guessing that it was compressing the deadbolt assembly too much and rubbing the internals. I got an [reinforcement ring](https://i0.wp.com/toledolocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/TA002SS.jpg?resize=1000%2C1000&ssl=1) to place between the the deadbolt and gate to extend it a bit.